# Xamarin Forms - GoToAsync page Termination

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin application that opens up a new page when a view is tapped. The function is:

```
private async void OpenSearchPage()
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SearchPage));
}
```

When I hit the back button, the page terminates (which is what I want for now). However, I want to know if I should worry about anything such as memory leaks. Is that something I should worry about?

Comment: `the page terminates (which is what I want for now)`  Did your  app crash? Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: Did you create a lot of data, that *you* stored in fields on that page? If you don't go "forward" (any links) from this page, you can clear by overriding `OnDisappearing`. BUT don't do that if you need this data when this page becomes visible again. (For "back" specifically, google adding custom code when "go back".) Don't worry about memory leaks in the UI itself. After back button, the page is removed from navigation stack. Xamarin Forms is responsible for "cleaning up" when a page is no longer on the navigation stack.

Comment: My app does not crash and there is no data on it yet. What I don't want is the app appearing to run smoothly while behind the scenes memory leaks are stacking up. I assume it's okay. All I want is extra verification that it is safe memory management. 

I plan on having my data variables (at least some) stored globally, so each page can have access to it. The page itself will not store any data.

Comment: As long as we use variables normally, there will be no memory leak. The premise, of course, is that we have a clear understanding of how variables are used and their lifetime.I think you can make a distinction between Local Variables,Global Variables and extern,Static Variables and Constant Variables .